# Wordpress / WooCommerce not displaying content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I was working with my new webshop using WooCommerce in Wordpress. Everything has been working great for weeks, but suddenly I went to my frontpage to take a look, and suddenly a lot of the content is missing, including the admin bar, which is weird. I have searched around for an answer but haven't been able to find anything. When I go to the blog page, everything seems normal. Product pages looks weird too - not like they used to. The buy now buttons are apparently using WooCommerce's default styling now. The footer is also missing on the front page.

Really, I have tried disabling plugins one by one, downgrading WooCommerce, reuploading header.php, but nothing has worked so far.

Has anybody experienced anything similar to this? I was just about to benefit from my traffic. ;)

http://fifacoincentral.com/

Comment: Have you enabled error logging checked that?

Comment: Yup, that doesn't pull up any errors sadly.

Comment: Are you sure enabled `WP_DEBUG`? If you 'view source' the page doesn't finish loading (HTML stops soon after the menu)..... which indicates some kind of error.

Comment: Pretty sure. I have now reuploaded wp-config.php to root folder with the following line changed.

define('WP_DEBUG', true);

I dont see anything, when I open the page.

Comment: When I checked given URL, I found there is error : **Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WooCommerce::get_image_size() in /home/fifaicfp/public_html/wp-content/themes/simple/library/core/twomediax-woo-integration.php on line 127** So remove that line and then try again.

Comment: That is weird. Can it be due to W3 Total Cache, that I don't see it? Where do I access this .php file? Should I go through FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading WooCommerce as few versions, which is not optimal, but it is now working. :)